# Sieve of Eratosthenes malfunction

Tags: java

I am trying to create a Sieve of Eratosthenes in Java but the code I wrote seems to be flawed.
I was wondering if anyone else can spot my mistake since I cannot. The output I get is simply [2], which means that my main loop doesn't work. I have only just started Java so I would appreciate it if you could give a detailed answer.

My code:

```
public static int[] primes(int n)
{
    //Variable assignement
    double sqrt;
    List<Integer> primes= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //Adds 2 to primes so i don't need to include the even numbers in my for loop.
    if(n>1)
    {
        primes.add(2);
    }
    //For loop that goes through the oneven numbers up to n
    for(int counter1=3;counter1<=n;counter1+=2)
    {
        sqrt=Math.floor(Math.sqrt(0.0+counter1));
        //for loop that tests if the first for loops number is prime
        for(int counter2=0;sqrt<=primes.get(counter2);counter2++)
        {
            if(counter1 % primes.get(counter2) != 0 && counter2 ==sqrt)
            {
                primes.add(counter1);
            }

            if(counter1 % primes.get(counter2)==0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return convertIntegers(primes);
}
//Converts the list to an array
public static int[] convertIntegers(List<Integer> integers)
{
    int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];
    for (int i=0; i < ret.length; i++)
    {
        ret[i] = integers.get(i).intValue();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your code a bit and apply a consistent pattern for the curly braces. Otherwise it's hard to read your code and see the different blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't throughly check your code but there might be a precision problem involved.
Note that `double` might not represent integer values precisely thus `counter2 ==sqrt` might be false even if `sqrt` seems to be an integer.

To prevent this, try the following:

```
//this is not necessarily a square root anymore, btw :)
int sqrt = (int) Math.floor( Math.sqrt( (double)counter1 ) );
...
for( ... ) {
  ...
  if(... && counter2 ==sqrt ) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

*Edit*:

A slightly more through analysis yields this:

Assume n = 5, thus the following steps would be executed in your code:

1. `counter1 = 3`
2. `sqrt = 1`  // floor(sqrt(2))
3. `counter2 = 0`
4. `counter1 % primes.get(counter2) != 0 && counter2 ==sqrt` is false since `3 % 2 = 1` BUT `0 != 1`
5. `counter1 % primes.get(counter2)==0` is false since `3 % 2 = 1`
6. `counter2 = 1` (next iteration)
7. `primes.get(counter2)` throws an exception since `primes.get(1)` needs `primes` to have at least 2 elements.

What you might try is `counter2 <=sqrt` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i tried to see if this resolved the issue, but it didn't. I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException in my second for loop but I can't find out why counter2 is bigger than the length of primes minus 1.

Comment: @Frank see my update for a breakdown of why you get that exception.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. Thanks for being patient with me:)

Answer (score 3):

```
if(counter1 % primes.get(counter2)==0);{
    break;}
}
```

is unlikely to help matters.  You have a semicolon before the opening brace - your break will always be executed.

Comment: Thank you, mcfinnigan. I feel like a noob. I, however, still get an error that says that my index is out of bounds.

Comment: Your code raises an IndexOutOfBoundsException here : `for(int counter2=0;sqrt<=primes.get(counter2);counter2++)` - you need to check that the list of primes is greater than or equal in length to the value of `counter2`.